# Is it OK to remove port 1433 from my SQL Server?

Tags: security, sql-server, remote-desktop

What are the consequences of removing 1433 all together ?

I plan on only using RDeskTop to access my sever.

- Any Reason why this a bad Idea ?

-Thank You

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: And how are you planning to "remove" it?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the ultimate purpose is to stop my App Log filling up with failed sa logon attempts. I figure if I drop 1433 no more brute force logon attempts.  Simple Quick ?

Comment: If I do not plan on remote logon why would I need it ???

Comment: How do you remove a port?

Answer (score 4):

In the comments above you stated

> the ultimate purpose is to stop my App Log filling up with failed sa
>   logon attempts. I figure if I drop 1433 no more brute force logon
>   attempts

Yes, shutting down MS SQL will stop it from accepting logons, including your own applications.

The proper (or ultimate purpose like you said) is to install a firewall, like any sane admin out there would do.

Comment: Did that (deny all except 80) and port 1433 does show as closed on an external scan....however...I continue to get failed 'sa' logon attempts ???? SQL-Injection precautions have been put in place (request filtering and c# Paramaters)...still getting logon attempts ???  - Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to prevent your log from filling up with failed login attempts, tell the server to stop logging them. In SSMS, right click on the server, go to Properties, and go to the Security tab. From there, there's a "Login Auditing" section that you can set to "None". Bingo... no more failed login attempt messages.